# Suddenly created meshes are invisible (even though they are checked as visible), cannot create any new objects now

Tags: mesh

as the title states I am suddenly unable to create any new objects, when i select a mesh from the "create" bar nothing noticeably happens, other than the object name appearing in the list in the top right hand corner of the screen, i cannot edit the object, view the object, or do anything at all to it, this happened suddenly part way through a project and has caused me to be unable to continue, it's driving me nuts and I cannot for the life of me see why this has suddenly happened, im sure i must have accidentally pressed a keyboard shortcut for something, but i do not know what, any ideas?

Comment: can you add a snapshot or a blend file?

Comment: Are you in local mode? Press the **/** key.

Comment: Try centering your view on the objects. Press 'Numbpad .' (Period).

Comment: it could also be that the far clipping plane of the viewport is cutting off objects that are beyond it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably activated **Local View** by pressing <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

When that happens you can only see and edit the selected object.

Press <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> again to exit (or press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and type Local view)

[image]

Comment: yes this was it! thank you so much, in the end i actually exported everything as a collada and then re-imported into a new file :\ but just went back and checked and this was what had happened, thank you this will help me avoid doing the same thing in the future

Answer (score 1):

Is your 3D cursor visible in the viewport? If not then the objects are probably wherever the cursor is.